# Nginx locations don't work without location /

Tags: nginx

why 2 locations in Nginx dont work if there is no location /. Or when I change proxy_pass & proxy_set_header in location /, other 2 locations don't work again. How to solve this? With this config 2 locations are opened:

```
  location /service2 {
    proxy_pass https://service2_url;
    proxy_set_header Host service2_url;
  }
  location /service1 {
    proxy_pass https://service1_url;
    proxy_set_header Host service1_url;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://service1_url;
    proxy_set_header Host service1_url;
  }
```

Comment: I suspect that some of the content in your `service1` or `service2` web pages is being requested without the `/service1/` or `/service2/` prefix. This is easily checked by looking at the Nginx access log. Not easy to fix though, without making changes to the service causing the problem,